# httpWebRequest timeout / failed connection after laptop hibernation and switching networks

Tags: .net, proxy, timeout, httpwebrequest

I have an odd issue where my app is trying to do an HTTPWebRequest POST to call an API.  Typically this goes through with no problem, however if a user takes their laptop home and connects via their home network, then hibernates the machine and returns to work the next day, the HTTPWebRequest fails with either a timeout error or simply that the URL could not be reached.  As soon as they restart the laptop, the connection is then usually fine again.

I spent numerous days trying to figure out what might be causing this, such as proxy connection issues or network card issues in the laptop, but no success in diagnosing or fixing yet.

Anyone have any suggestions on what the problem might be or how I can better diagnose this?

Code:

```
Private Function WRequestMainDynamic(URL As String, method As String, POSTdata As String, timeout As Integer, Optional ByRef proxyType As Integer = 0)
    Dim responseData As String = ""
    Dim hwrequest As Net.HttpWebRequest = Nothing
    Dim postByteArray() As Byte = Nothing
    Dim connectionSuccess As Boolean = False
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    While connectionSuccess = False And count < 6
        Try
            hwrequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(URL)
            hwrequest.Accept = "*/*"
            hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
            hwrequest.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1"
            hwrequest.Timeout = timeout
            hwrequest.Method = method
            hwrequest.KeepAlive = True

            Select Case proxyType
                Case 0
                    hwrequest.Proxy = Nothing
                Case 1
                'don't set anything
                Case 2
                    hwrequest.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
                Case Else
                    hwrequest.Proxy = Nothing
            End Select

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False

            If hwrequest.Method = "POST" Then
                hwrequest.ContentType = "application/json"
                Dim encoding As New Text.UTF8Encoding() 'Use UTF8Encoding for XML requests
                postByteArray = encoding.GetBytes(POSTdata)
                hwrequest.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length
                Using postStream As IO.Stream = hwrequest.GetRequestStream()
                    postStream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length)
                End Using
            End If

            Using hwresponse As Net.HttpWebResponse = hwrequest.GetResponse()
                If hwresponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                    Using responseStream As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(hwresponse.GetResponseStream())
                        responseData = responseStream.ReadToEnd()
                    End Using
                End If
            End Using

            connectionSuccess = True

        Catch webex As WebException
            If webex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.Timeout Then
                Throw
            Else
                proxyType += 1
                If proxyType = 3 Then proxyType = 0
                count += 1
                If count = 6 Then Throw
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            Throw
            responseData = ""
        Finally
            postByteArray = Nothing
            hwrequest = Nothing
            GC.Collect()
        End Try
    End While
```

Comment: Use system.net logging features ( http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html ) to see what server it is trying to connect to after hibernation.

Comment: Thanks how would I add / integrate this config file with my app (Outlook add-in project), I have an app.config file, is this where I should add it?

Comment: yeah, add it to the app.config file for your control.

Comment: Thanks problem solved! Turns out using hwrequest.Proxy = Nothing was able to connect using the client's wifi, however when they plugged in a LAN cable it then started to fail.  Changing the default to my Case 1 above worked for both.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like different proxies require different configuration with the Proxy property of the Net.HttpWebRequest object, and even different connection types WiFi/LAN act differently too.

In most case not doing anything with it works fine, however we have found sometimes you need to specifically set the Proxy.Credentials to the default ones as it fails to get them automatically, and in other cases it is easier to set Proxy = Nothing to bypass it altogether.

To account for all scenarios, we embed all three into the code as per above and pass in a ByRef proxyType variable that stores the latest one (as integer) that connects fine.  On each HttpRequest, if it fails then loop over the other methods in case one of those works, if so then pass that back in the variable to use in the next call.  If all fail after X number of attempts then raise an exception.

The code in my original question does this, just make sure to correctly pass back in the proxyType variable each time!